# setting MaxFunEvals in arima and estimate command

Tags: matlab

I am using arima to forecast a time series. The code I currently have is (NRV is the data to be fitted):

```
temp = arima('D',1,'ARLags',[1:3],'MALags',[1:3],'SMALags',[96,96*7],'Seasonality',96);
ARIMA24 = estimate(temp,NRV);
save('ARIMA24','ARIMA24')
res24 = infer(ARIMA24,NRV);
save('res24','res24')
clear temp
```

when I run this code, I get an error stating:

Solver stopped prematurely.

```
fmincon stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit,
options.MaxFunEvals = 1000 (the default value).
```

I tried setting the MaxFunEvals for fmincon by using the code below, but I get an error message.

```
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',2000)
temp = arima('D',1,'ARLags',[1:3],'MALags',[1:3],'SMALags',[96,96*7],'Seasonality',96);
ARIMA24 = estimate(temp,NRV,'Options',options);
save('ARIMA24','ARIMA24') % variance = [6183.97370342290;]
res24 = infer(ARIMA24,NRV);
save('res24','res24')
clear temp
```

error message:

```
Argument 'Options' did not match
any valid parameter of the
parser.
```

I was hoping some of the members here know how to set the MaxFunEvals in the estimate command.

Comment: Have you tried 'options' instead of 'Options'?

Comment: I just tried it, but it gives me the following error:

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in arima/estimate>linearConstraints (line
1095)
LB(i1:i2) = [-10 ; repmat(-1 + tolerance, nAR +
nMA, 1) ; tolerance(isVarianceConstant)];

Error in arima/estimate (line 755)
     conStruct = linearConstraints(LagsAR,
     LagsSAR, LagsMA, LagsSMA, ...

Comment: Does the same code work without setting the options (i.e. your first example)? Looks like a bug

Comment: @Dmitry Galchinsky Yes the code works, and I get the resulting arima model. However the above message is displayed stating that the solver stopped prematurely. I am hoping that if I could set the MaxFunEval limit I can get a better fit.

Comment: `ARIMA24 = estimate(temp,NRV,'options', optimset('MaxFunEvals', 2000));` should work as well as `ARIMA24 = estimate(temp,NRV);`. That's why I say that it looks like a bug

Comment: the code you suggests gives the same error as above. `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in arima/estimate>linearConstraints (line
1095)
LB(i1:i2) = [-10 ; repmat(-1 + tolerance, nAR +
nMA, 1) ; tolerance(isVarianceConstant)];

Error in arima/estimate (line 755)
     conStruct = linearConstraints(LagsAR,
     LagsSAR, LagsMA, LagsSMA, ... `

Comment: Looks like a bug in their code. I think you'd better send a report about it

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. The problem is, that the option you need to change is in the fmincon function. To this this I guess you have to "call" this function, before changing the option. It can be done in the following way:

```
options = optimset('fmincon');
options = optimset(options,'Algorithm','sqp','TolCon',1e-7,'MaxFunEvals',...
    3000,'Display','iter','Diagnostics','on');
```

This code keeps the deafult values, while changing the MaxFunEvals.

Comment: But then why does the other change in options cause the code to crash?